# How can I print node author's last login date on page.tpl.php?

Tags: 6, nodes, theming

I could easily find out how to print the current user's last login date but what about the node author's one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to put this logic in an preprocess function rather than directly in the template file, but the code would probably be something like this:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $author = user_load($node->uid);
  $last_login = $author->login;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `hook_preprocess_page()` you can simply use the following code.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node']) && ($account = user_load($variables['node']->uid))) {
    $variables['author_last_login'] = $account->login;
  }
}
```

In your page.tpl.php file you can then print `$autor_last_login`, with `format_date($autor_last_login)`, for example.

Bear in mind that `$account->login` is the last time the user has logged in; it is not the last time the user has been seen. For that you need `$account->access`.